# View which Bash profile scripts were loaded

Tags: macos, bash

Is there a way in Bash to view which "dot files" were loaded, and in what order they were loaded in?

I'm trying to **authoritatively** figure out which Bash profile files were loaded, and what order they were loaded in, on Mac OS X.

Comment: Not that I know of. You could do it with strace or similar for a given run but that's not exactly reasonable.

Comment: Either `strace -e trace=file bash`, as @EtanReisner is suggesting, or put an `echo "In path/to/dotfile"` as the first line of each potential "dot file"...

Comment: @twalberg: Helpful, but note that on OS X you'd have to use `sudo opensnoop -n bash` (`opensnoop` is a wrapper around `dtrace` - the OS X equivalent of Linux' `strace`).

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't know how to determine this *dynamically*, on any given OS X system, *without any preparatory work*.

However, *with* preparatory work as an option, Etan Reisner and twalberg offer helpful options in their comments:

- Trace the files that `bash` opens when a new shell is created - see below.
- If you know the set of candidate files, edit each and put something like `echo "Loading file <filename>..."` at the top.

  - `man bash` should list all candidate files
  - The disadvantage of this approach, apart from being cumbersome, is that you'll also have to manually scan the *contents* of these files, to see if they load *other* files (and so on, transitively); for instance, the particular code in standard profile file `/etc/profile` on OS X loads non-standard file `/etc/bashrc`, which in turn (since OS X 10.11) loads `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal`.

---

**Tracing the files opened by a `bash` shell during startup:**

[`opensnoop`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/opensnoop.1m.html) is a shell script wrapper around the [`dtrace` utility](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtrace.1.html) that comes with OS X and that you can use as follows:

**Caveat** (tip of the hat to [4ae1e1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1944784/4ae1e1)): With the introduction of [SIP (System Integrity Protection)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) in **OS X 10.11**, **`opensnoop` no longer works with executables in system locations** such as `/bin/`, `/sbin/` and `/usr/bin`, which includes `bash`.
**DTrace - and thus `opensnoop` - *can* be made to work in these locations**, but only if you boot into the recovery partition, select `Utilities > Terminal`, and execute
`csrutil enable --without dtrace` there; note, however, that you'll get the following **dire warning**: `csrutil: requesting an unsupported configuration. This is likely to break in the future and leave your machine in an unknown state.`
A **pragmatic workaround** is to **copy `/bin/bash` to a user-specific location and execute it from there** - see below.

- Run `sudo opensnoop -n bash` in an existing Terminal window.
- Open a new Terminal window, which starts another `bash` instance.

  - **OS X 10.11+** (SIP workaround):

    - Ignore the `invalid user access in action ...` error messages you're seeing initially.
    - Assuming you've (temporarily) copied your `bash` executable to a location other than `/bin/`, `/sbin/` or `/usr/bin` - such as to `~` - launch it with `~/bash -l`, which emulates how `Terminal.app` creates a new instance (it creates an interactive *logon* shell).
- Examine the output from the `opensnoop` command:

  - Luckily, it even shows *unsuccessful* attempts to open files - indicated by value `-1` in the `FD` column, which tells you which files `bash` *tries* to open, and in what order; note that in the case of the `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` and `~/.profile` troika only the *first* one that actually exists is opened.

Example output from a pristine OS X 10.10 system:

```
  UID    PID COMM          FD PATH                 
  501   5110 bash           3 /dev/dtracehelper    
  501   5110 bash           3 /dev/tty             
  501   5110 bash           3 /usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE 
  501   5110 bash           3 /usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE 
  501   5110 bash           3 /usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY 
  501   5110 bash           3 /usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC 
  501   5110 bash           3 /usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_TIME 
  501   5110 bash           3 /usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/LC_MESSAGES 
  501   5110 bash          -1 /etc/.mdns_debug     
  501   5110 bash           3 /etc/profile         
  501   5110 bash           3 /etc/bashrc          
  501   5110 bash          -1 /Users/jdoe/.bash_profile 
  501   5110 bash          -1 /Users/jdoe/.bash_login 
  501   5110 bash          -1 /Users/jdoe/.profile 
  501   5110 bash           3 /Users/jdoe/.bash_history 
  501   5110 bash           3 /Users/jdoe/.bash_history 
  501   5110 bash           3 /usr/share/terminfo/78/xterm-256color
```

Comment: "`opensnoop` is currently broken on OS X 10.11.1": why do you think it's broken (it seems to work just fine for me)? Have you filed open radar (seems not)?

Comment: @4ae1e1: All I get when I run `sudo opensnoop -n bash` and then open another Terminal window is error messages along the lines of `dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 5 (ID 152: syscall::open:return): invalid user access in action #11 at DIF offset 24`. What do you get? I'll file an [openradar](https://openradar.appspot.com) bug if we agree that there's a bug.

Comment: Ah yes, now I can reproduce. It happens with all executables under `/bin`, `/usr` (minus `/usr/local`), etc. This is the expected behavior on 10.11 with the DTrace Restrictions part of SIP turned on (`csrutil status`), so it's just an unfortunate fact of life — no need for bug report I guess. I was using shells installed under `/usr/local` so didn't catch that on the first run :)

Comment: By the way, in case you don't know, you can turn off DTrace Restrictions with `csrutil enable --without dtrace` from the recovery partition if you really want to.

Comment: Excellent background info, @4ae1e1, thanks - I had no idea. Answer updated, including the dire warning you get when you do run `csrutil enable --without dtrace` from the recovery partition.